# how to add lastmodifieddate in aggregate list

Tags: apex, soql, query, account, aggregate

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults;
if(Schema.Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isAccessible())

  groupedResults = [SELECT Name,  FROM Account where Name like :sql or name IN:sql1 Group By Name Order By LastModifiedDate Desc limit 5];
```

Above my query is throwing error,that `LastModifiedDate` can't be grouped. But I want to display the 5 records which are be modified recently.

Comment: System.UnexpectedException: field 'lastModifiedDate' can not be grouped in a query call,,getting the above error.

Comment: Did you check this link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/how-to-sort-a-custom-list-of-notes-and-attachments-by-lastmodifieddate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do need to group the Accounts by name for some reason, and you only want to do this for the 5 accounts that were most recently modified, I think you can use one of the following two options:

**Two Queries**

```
List<Account> recentlyModified = [
    SELECT ID 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Name LIKE :sql OR name IN:sql1
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 5
    ];

AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [
    SELECT Name 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id IN :recentlyModified
    GROUP BY Name 
    ];
```

**1 Query and a Map**

```
List<Account> recentlyModified = [
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Name LIKE :sql OR name IN:sql1
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 5
    ];

//now group the Accounts by Name in a Map
Map<String, List<Account>> groupedResults = new Map<String, List<Account>();
for(Account acc : recentlyModified){
    if(groupedResults.containsKey(acc.Name)){
        groupedResults.get(acc.Name).add(acc);
    }else{
        groupedResults.put(acc.Name, new Account[]{acc});
    }
}
```

The above answer by Adrian Larson is correct and I voted for it, but I was in the middle of writing mine, so I figured I'd post it nonetheless as it gives a slightly different approach which can be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the 5 most recent `Account` records:

- Remove the comma (`,`) after the `Name` field in your `SELECT` clause.
- Remove the `GROUP BY` clause entirely if you want individual records.
- In tandem with the above, assign to a `List<Account>` instead of `List<AggregateResult>`.

So change it to:

```
List<Account> mostRecent = [
    SELECT Name FROM Account
    WHERE Name like :sql or name IN:sql1
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
    LIMIT 5
];
```

Notice you don't have to declare and assign the list separately. Better to do both in the same line when you can.

One more note. You want to avoid `OR` clauses if at all possible in your queries. They tend to run inefficiently. Add `sql` to the `sql1` collection and just filter on that.

```
sql1.add(sql);
// then inside your query: 
    ... WHERE Name IN :sql1
```